# vertical split panel not created in vaadin

Tags: vaadin, vaadin7

Hi folks i am new to vaadin,I am trying to create tiles like structure using vaadin,first two layout vertical split layout and horizontal split layout create successfully but when i tried to create last vertical layout (footer) i getting the following error

Error:
   **java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Split panel can contain only two components**

```
**//header**    
    VerticalLayout mainLayout = new VerticalLayout();
    mainLayout.addComponent(new Label("Header"));
    setSplitPosition(15, Sizeable.UNITS_PERCENTAGE);
    addComponent(mainLayout);

**//Hub**   
    HorizontalSplitPanel hpanel = new HorizontalSplitPanel();
    addComponent(hpanel);
    hpanel.setSplitPosition(15, Sizeable.UNITS_PERCENTAGE);
    Button loginbutton = new Button("Login");
    hpanel.setFirstComponent(loginbutton);
    hpanel.setSecondComponent(new Label("Welcome to Vaadin"));

**// Footer**
    //VerticalLayout mainLayout2 = new VerticalLayout();
    mainLayout.addComponent(new Label("Footer"));
    setSplitPosition(15, Sizeable.UNITS_PERCENTAGE);
    addComponent(mainLayout);
```

Comment: for down voters i am beginner to this forum,as well as vaadin if u give negative mark for my post how i again post my doubt here,instead of downvoting its better to provide some information like what mistake i have done,its better i will  correct on my next post

Comment: your code there looks ok (only calls `set(First|Second)Component` which is fine.  The error might be somewhere along the road.  The SplitPanels still have the addComponent() methods and you might call them somewhere by accident.  the stacktrace (which should show with the error message) would give you pin point location.

Answer (score 2):

assuming, that the whole code is from one class, which subclasses a "split"-oid layout (because of the call to `setSplitPosition` in the footer) you are calling `addComponent` three times.  A split layout may only hold two components (which the error message states).  A look into the stacktrace of the error message should have given you a clear clue where to look for this error.